# Align image to bottom

Tags: html, css

I have two divs side by side, one with text and other with an image [CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/elzFk):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="p1">    
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.        
  </div>
  <div class="p2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
 </div>    
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  .clear;
}

div.p1, div.p2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

div.p1 {font-size: 36px;}
```

There is a space on image bottom when the text is higher than the image.

I would like the image to be always aligned to bottom.

**UPDATE**

Was able to align both to bottom using inline-block but I am not able to use 50% for divs width ... Why? How to solve this?

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: always ? or only when text is higher than image ?

Comment: Only when text is higher then image ... But when the image is higher that naturally it will be next to bottom border of parent div or am I missing something?

Comment: http://cdpn.io/elzFk , do you want to work auotmatically like this ?

Comment: Yes, but why do you set the width to 49% and not 50%? I am using this in a responsive design and not using the exact values can be a problem ... I think ... If I use 50% the image goes under the text. And why 49% and not 48% or 47% or ... I don't understand why 50% does not work.

Comment: check my answer , maybe this is what you are seeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
html:

```
<div class="wrapper clear">
  <div class="p1">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.        
  </div>
  <div class="p2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
  </div>    
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper {
   border: 1px solid red;
   width: 400px;
   position:relative;
}

.p1{
   font-size: 36px;
   display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
  float:left;
  padding:0;
   width: 50%;
}

.p2{
  margin:0;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: bottom;
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
   width: 50%;
   img{display: block;}
}


.clear {

  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  } // :after

} // clear
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/byIda

Edited:
See this one
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/klivC/

Comment: That does not put the image at bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
   border: 1px solid red;
   width: 400px;
}

.p1{
   font-size: 36px;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 40%;
}

.p2{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: You set the width as 40%. If I set to 50% the image goes under the text ... If I set to 49% then it works fine ... Any idea why? In theory I should be able to use 50%.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to add `white-space:nowrap;` to your wrapper class.

```
.wrapper {
   border: 1px solid red;
   width: 400px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

http://cdpn.io/elzFk

Comment: That comes with a problem ... the text will stay all in one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
   border: 1px solid red;
   width: 400px;
}

.p1{
   font-size: 36px;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 40%;
}

.p2{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   width: 40%;
}
```

When you do the above with width:50%, you have to delete all whitespaces between the divs's. That is, because inline-blocks positioning is just like an <img> dependent on whitespaces around them.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is I need the two divs to be 100% width and yours don't ... Ok I can set to 49% but will I be sure that with this percentage will always fit 100% or is there a situation where the p2 will come under p1. The problem is that I will need to make this responsive ...